# How to connect to a client server database in PhoneGap?

Tags: mysql, database, cordova, client-server

I have been searching this topic for a long time but I haven't found the answer I wanted. I want to connect to a MySQL database on a client-server and insert some info on a table using an app I made using PhoneGap. I found things like that but didn't seem to do what I want them to do: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.7.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#SQLTransaction
This documentation page doesn't make any sense to me.

Does anyone know how can I solve my problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You normally don't access database on your server dirrectly from the app in your phone.

The doc you saw about SQLTransaction is about writing data to the SQLite database that is inside your device, not to write to a remote database.

What is usually done to communicate with a remote database is we perform http requests to a web server (php, java, .net, ruby, perl or whatever you like) and that server will communicate with the database server.

If you really want to communicate with your mysql server from your phonegap app, you would have to include native mysql libraries in your project and write native code to communicate with the mysql server. And I don't think it woule work very well through a data connection...